# app stops responding simulator w/o any error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios-simulator

I have an app which I am testing using the iPhone simulator. 
When I click Build and Debug, the program executes upto certain line and then seems to stop without any error.

1. I do not have any breakpoints ON.
2. In Console, I see NSLog o/p for upto line X and then see (gdb). There is no error. But for some reason it is not printing the o/p after line X
3. The iphone seems to be frozen and does not respond.

I am not sure where my app is stuck. Please help.

Comment: some code, logs, general description of what is your application doing will be helpful

Comment: ok..actually I am using libxml2 for making some ext API requests and then do some calculation. There are multiple NSLogs that I have used in my app. But as I said after line X, it does not print the other logs and also does not give any error. SO I do not know what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see (gdb) in the run log, it means that something has tripped it (e.g., a breakpoint or certain code errors) and caused XCode to pause the process and load it into the debugger. This can happen even without any breakpoints on. Open up the debugger console in XCode and look at the stack trace for the tripping thread to see where the hangup is.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with a xib file.  Make sure your delegates/outlets are properly connected.

Comment: I do not think it is a XIB issue. Actually it was working fine. But I was trying out some breakpoints/ adding NSLogs and then something seemed to have happened. I am not very sure, but as I said, as of now , there are no breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure that your `NSLog` statements are set up correctly. That could be the problem, seeing as you said you were adding `NSLog`s.